# wordpress timthumb.php vulnerability

Tags: php, wordpress, exploit

I am trying to upload remotely a php file into a web page, it has TimThumb version : 1.28 with the well known timthumb.php vurnable file. but after I upload the php file when I open it from its cache it doesnt execute! I dont know what stops it from executing! I saw the changes they made in the timthumb.php where they add .txt to every file that goes into the cache folder, but it was added in a newer version not in this version, so I am really confused what stops it from executing! By the way this is just for learning purpose.

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file's named `whatever.php.txt` on the server, then it's going to be seen as a TEXT file by the server, not a PHP file, and served up as such. You could tell the server to treat .txt files as PHP files, which'd run the file+code through the PHP interpreter, but then you've simply re-opened the security hole that timthumb patched with the `.txt` addition.

e.g. you'd still be vulnerable to remote hacks.

Comment: I dont have access to that web page, I am trying to gain access to understand how it works, because till now I have only programmed but I dont have the knowledge to protect the system. so now I am trying to learn how they do it.